# cannot find my jar in private maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, local, cloudbees

When i ran the build in Jenkins, its successful, and i was able to deploy it as well. 
But i could not find my jar file in my maven repository private/release location

https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/release/

Here is the Jenkins console output

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Projects to build: [MavenProject: com.uhg.jcoe:osa-common:1.0.0 @ /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/pom.xml]
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/pom.xml to /home/ram-cloud/hudson_home/jobs/osa-common build/modules/com.uhg.jcoe$osa-common/builds/2013-03-16_19-13-30/archive/com.uhg.jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/osa-common-1.0.0.jar to /home/ram-cloud/hudson_home/jobs/osa-common build/modules/com.uhg.jcoe$osa-common/builds/2013-03-16_19-13-30/archive/com.uhg.jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins) to the ram-cloud account
```

See it says it had deployed to ram-cloud account, but i could not see it and thats why my other projects fail, as they have this jar dependancy.

Comment: can you post a more complete log ? The lines before BUILD SUCCESS. What mvn command are running ?

Comment: What Maven goal did you tell Jenkins to build?

Comment: Sure. [INFO] Installing /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/osa-common-1.0.0.jar to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/pom.xml to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.pom
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1(default-install)
projectSucceeded com.uhg.jcoe:osa-common:1.0.0
sessionEnded

Comment: Executing Maven:  -B -f /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/pom.xml install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Comment: [debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-resources)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-compile)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ osa-common ---

Comment: [INFO] Compiling 25 source files to /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/classes

Comment: [debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ osa-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource

Comment: [INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ osa-common ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/test-classes

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.2:test (default-test) @ osa-common ---[INFO] Tests are skipped.
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.2(default-test)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2(default-jar)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ osa-common ---

Comment: [INFO] Building jar: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/osa-common-1.0.0.jar
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2(default-jar)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1(default-install)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ osa-common ---

Comment: [INFO] Installing /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/target/osa-common-1.0.0.jar to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /scratch/jenkins/workspace/osa-common build/pom.xml to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.pom
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1(default-install)
projectSucceeded com.uhg.jcoe:osa-common:1.0.0
sessionEnded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: I didnt tell any goal specific to jenkins, do i need to :)

Comment: I am very silly, trying to deploy, without deploy goal , i added "clean deploy" goal to maven

Comment: When it ran it is expecting the following  <distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
  <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

Comment: What should i enter for the above ?  For SVN repo i have https://svn-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/osa/trunk/osa-common  for snapshots i am going to try https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/

Comment: message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project osa-common: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.uhg.jcoe:osa-common:jar:1.0.0 from/to private (https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/): Failed to transfer file: https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar. Return code is: 405, ReasonPhrase:Method Not Allowed.

Comment: POM.XML IS AS BELOW   <distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
  <repository>
   <id>private</id>
   <name>Cloud private</name>
   <url>https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
  <snapshotRepository>
   <id>snapshot</id>
   <name>Cloud snapshot</name>
   <url>https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>

Comment: changed to  <distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
  <repository>
   <id>private</id>
   <name>Cloud private</name>
   <url>https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/private</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
  <snapshotRepository>
   <id>snapshot</id>
   <name>Cloud snapshot</name>
   <url>https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>

Comment: got this error :: Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/private/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorize

Comment: yay finally worked, Deploying the main artifact osa-common-1.0.0.jar
Uploading: dav:https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar

Uploaded: dav:https://repository-ram-cloud.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/uhg/jcoe/osa-common/1.0.0/osa-common-1.0.0.jar (37 KB at 185.6 KB/sec)

Comment: Thank you very much, http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository

Comment: OP: Too much information is being posted into the comments. Why not move this into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in log is jenkins archiving the built result, but this is *only* a Jenkins feature, not related to maven repositories. For this artifact to be available to other jobs you need to configure a post-build action "deploy to my maven repository" and select "release".

Answer (score 0):

A rough summary of the comment obfuscated solution is:

You need to tell maven to actually deploy the artifacts so they are usable between builds:

```
maven clean deploy
```

Your POM also needed to be configured correctly - as per 
[CloudBees Private Maven Repository](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository)